# What exactly does Django UserProfile give me?

Tags: django, user-profile

I was reading about Django's support for custom user profiles. I understand that if I do the following steps, I will be able to tie in a custom user profile object with my application.

1. Create a model object for UserProfile which will have django.contrib.auth.models..User as a FK
2. Add the following to settings.py AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.UserProfile'
3. Ensure that a UserProfile object is available for every User object (either using django signals, or creating one when it is queried)

By doing all this what I get is the ability to obtain a user profile by doing

```
user.get_profile()
```

My question is, is there any other functionality I get, such as (non admin) views to view/edit the user profile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no added functionality at all. The only thing Django is doing is providing a simple way (via `get_profile`) to reverse the relationship between django's default `contrib.auth.models.User` and a custom model (usually a `UserProfile` - although this could be anything). The alternative is to reverse the relationship yourself, something like:

```
my_user.userprofile_set.all()[0]
```

which is obviously inconvenient.

If you want added functionality, you need to look at something like [`django-profiles`](http://code.google.com/p/django-profiles/) (to add the views for editing a profile) and [`django-registration`](http://code.google.com/p/django-registration/) (to add sign-up views)

Comment: Thanks. I am new to django and kind of new to Python also. Can you please explain what 'my_user.userprofile_set.all()[0]' does ?

Comment: If you have a `UserProfile` object and you want to get the related `User` you just follow the relationship "forward" by accessing the foreignkey attribute - `my_user_profile.user`. Alternatively, if you have a `User` object and you want to get the related `UserProfile` object, you can also follow the relationship "backward". But there could (technically) by numerous `UserProfiles` for a single `User` so you get all of them `userprofile_set.all()` and choose the first from the resulting queryset `[0]`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: Thanks. I was confused because my UserProfile has a 'unique=True' attribute for User. I should have realized that other configurations are also possible.

Comment: `unique=True` makes sense as it means that a `UserProfile` can only belong to one particular `User` but you could omit that meaning that there could technically be more then one `UserProfile` per `User` (although I'm not sure how `get_profile` would manage this)

Answer (score 1):

User profile allow you only to extend standard user model. You don`t get any additional functionality.